how to create multi select list in oracle apex?
I have a table called Employees with Employee_id , Employee_Name columns,job,and product. Now i want to create a page to insert these data. the item for product with type of select list or LOV and allow multi select, store thes values i had selected into a database column in a table . The problem i am facing is to how to create that multi select list and store the select values in these table.i tried to do that using column data type "varchar 2" and in the specification of page item i have used the multi select is "yes"
Is there an Item for multi select? If not, how should i do it?

Apex designed Shuttle item for such a purpose. It lets you select values on the left hand side and move them to the right hand side of the item. For example:

Submit will store them into a varchar2 datatype column (so yes - that's what product column's datatype should be; make it long enough to accept all values you expect).
As shuttle item is just *another LoV, its select looks like
select product_name as display_value,
       product_id   as return_value
from products

Presuming you selected 3 products, they will be stored as a colon-separated list of return_value values; for example, 1347:32:54882.

This works just fine in Apex environment. However, note that - if you write your own queries against the product column - you'll have to split them into rows so that these ID values can be joined to the products table (or any other that contains that info).
Furthermore, such a storage (colon-separated list) will prevent creation of a foreign key constraint so you'll have to enforce it via database trigger.
Because of all of that, consider creating a master-detail relationship between your current table and a new table which would contain employee_id and product_id columns; such a data model would then be normalized.

In APEX 24.1 there are 4 item types that allow multi select: shuttle, select list, select many (new in 24.1), popup lov. Up to you to decide which one best suits the business requirement.
As for the how to process this - ideally the data model matches the UI. If a entity has an attribute that allows multi select, then this should be represented as a child table in the data model. Failing to do so will result in complex queries and give you headaches later on in the project.
A multi-value page item is sumbitted to the server on page submit as a colon separated list. This is not handled by the native form process but needs to be processed so the colon-separated list is split into scalar values and the corresponding child table has rows added/removed. APEX provides a some methods that make this pretty straightforward (APEX_STRING.SPLIT and APEX_STRING.JOIN). Have a look at this post with a similar example on how to process multi value item data.
